# error installing c++ mySQL connector

Tags: mysql, linux, cmake, mysql-connector

I'm trying to install a C++ MySQL connector on a centOS 6.4 64bit machine.
I've installed MySQL 5.6 ( a server and client component, and an additional shared   component in order to get the mysqlclient.s0 libraries ) It seems to work fine.

On the site I've found the following file :
**Red Hat/Oracle Enterprise Linux ver. 6 (x86, 64-bit), Compressed TAR Archive**
After reading the INSTALL file I've tried to invoke `cmake .` , but got an error about a  missing CMakeLists.txt.
Later I found out I need the actual source code in the drop down pane :
**Generic Linux (Architecture Independent), Compressed TAR Archive**
there is a CMakeLists.txt file in the directory of the the source code
and I am able to run : `cmake .`

- why is there also the platform specific download ?
- Can I get by with only the source code ?

when I run cmake . from the directory, I get the following output:

> CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:   A logical block opening on
>   the line
>
> ```
> /home/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.3-linux-el6-x86-64bit/source/CMakeLists.txt:39
> ```
>
> (if)
>
> closes on the line
>
> ```
> /home/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.3-linux-el6-x86-64bit/source/CMakeLists.txt:41
> ```
>
> (endif)
>
> with mis-matching arguments. This warning is for project developers.
>   Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> -- Environment compile flags:
>   -- Environment link flags:  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:120 (MESSAGE):   Boost or some of its libraries found.  If not in standard
>   place please set   -DBOOST_ROOT:STRING=
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

this is the content of lines around line CMakeLists.txt:39-41  :

```
if(COMMAND cmake_policy AND POLICY CMP0015)
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0015 NEW)
endif(COMMAND cmake_policy)
```

this is the content of lines around line CMakeLists.txt:120  :

```
IF(NOT Boost_FOUND)
    # Try dynamic
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS FALSE)
    FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS ${MYSQLCPPCONN_BOOST_COMPONENTS})
    IF(NOT Boost_FOUND)
        MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Boost or some of its libraries found. If not in standard place please set -DBOOST_ROOT:STRING=")
    ENDIF(NOT Boost_FOUND)
ENDIF(NOT Boost_FOUND)
```

- I don't understand. did it find the boost components or it didn't ?
  and if it did, why is this an error?
- I've installed/updated boost components with : yum install boost
  this is the output of a :

  find / -name *boost*

  /usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_system.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_graph-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_date_time-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_wserialization-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_unit_test_framework.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_signals-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_date_time.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_regex.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_prg_exec_monitor-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_wave-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_serialization-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_program_options-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_graph.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_signals.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_python.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_iostreams.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_serialization.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_python-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_iostreams-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_program_options.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_regex-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_wserialization.so.5
  /usr/include/c++/4.4.4/tr1_impl/boost_sp_counted_base.h
  /usr/include/c++/4.4.4/bits/boost_concept_check.h
  /usr/share/icons/oxygen/22x22/actions/mixer-microphone-front-boost.png
  /usr/share/icons/oxygen/22x22/actions/mixer-microphone-boost.png
  /usr/share/doc/boost-regex-1.41.0
  /usr/share/doc/boost-signals-1.41.0
  /usr/share/doc/boost-system-1.41.0
  /usr/share/doc/boost-iostreams-1.41.0
  /usr/share/doc/boost-thread-1.41.0
  /usr/share/doc/boost-filesystem-1.41.0
  /usr/share/doc/boost-program-options-1.41.0
  /usr/share/doc/boost-test-1.41.0
  /usr/share/doc/boost-wave-1.41.0
  /usr/share/doc/boost-date-time-1.41.0
  /usr/share/doc/boost-python-1.41.0
  /usr/share/doc/boost-serialization-1.41.0
  /usr/share/doc/boost-graph-1.41.0
  /var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/c353df239962740ed530d499bb76180201aa8a1f-boost-program-options-1.41.0-17.el6_4-x86_64
  /var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/b2292fc632d0f893a2efc41c077bcc88a83649cc-boost-filesystem-1.41.0-17.el6_4-x86_64
  /var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/137b574a8590a642229c2eaa20c0c98bd4c367e8-boost-python-1.41.0-17.el6_4-x86_64
  /var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/54cc53886ae5c9f0a36e3e55abe8cc44d30b0c88-boost-date-time-1.41.0-17.el6_4-x86_64
  /var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/b17dfa289b3c0e615f7e598c288dbc09dcce09b6-boost-wave-1.41.0-17.el6_4-x86_64
  /var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/5cca310e29fc5639ae673069c639327b03029c2e-boost-serialization-1.41.0-17.el6_4-x86_64
  /var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/c5bea6cfd9e95fb42d1ff7ff26068f52dde8d3c0-boost-test-1.41.0-17.el6_4-x86_64
  /var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/4426c89bd11acd85e92fb4eafe011351944a81ea-boost-1.41.0-17.el6_4-x86_64
  /var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/e6fddb18e7fd66b59d3cb6aa5061436592ee81ef-boost-iostreams-1.41.0-17.el6_4-x86_64
  /var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/6b2fcabdebbbf0f3dda98bad6ea4c259b366f571-boost-signals-1.41.0-17.el6_4-x86_64
  /var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/8bda127d59cc392fe94ec251d3514c7512100333-boost-system-1.41.0-17.el6_4-x86_64
  /var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/d75110a5f95a50a32cd3554afd35a95d3c3c1eea-boost-regex-1.41.0-17.el6_4-x86_64
  /var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/f06fb95c4bcec8c01bd24bf89600ca743b13f6bd-boost-thread-1.41.0-17.el6_4-x86_64
  /var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/a44d43b7ec316bf9e52b6d16973775c7a99271df-boost-graph-1.41.0-17.el6_4-x86_64

I've tried to run the cmake . with the following parameters without luck :

```
cmake . -DBOOST_ROOT:STRING=/usr/lib64/
```

and

```
cmake . -DBOOST_ROOT:STRING=/usr/share/doc/
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to make it work with the dynamic libraries that were found under :
/usr/lib64/
(I had any libraries because I've ran :
`yum install boost`)
I've decided to try with static ones.
After I've downloaded [boost](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.54.0/) :
I just had to point to the parent directory :

```
cmake . -DBOOST_ROOT:STRING=/home/boost_1_54_0/
```

and the cmake finished without a problem.

One might try to make the cmake process work with the dynamic libraries,
but the CMakeLists.txt file should be edited accordingly.
for example

```
SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)
```

should be changed.